# Recurring profile gets canceled by itself after creation

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, recurring

I am implementing Paypal recurring API. In sandbox mode when i create a recurring profile using `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile`, it returns success as response and then it instantly Cancels the Recurring profile. It worked fine for me before and now it happens every time i create a new recurring profile. First i i was passing  `CancelOnFailure` for `FAILEDINITAMTACTION` as a parameter. Now i have removed it and it still cancels the recurring profile.

Comment: Can you include a full copy of your API request and response for CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile (minus your API credentials) please?

Comment: @PayPal_Robert Thanks for the comment, but it got fixed, i checked the merchant account and the negative testing was on, now i turned it off and it works fine.

Comment: Hah. Yes, that would do it. Glad you got it fixed.